# Is there a function to check for lines of a certain value in a array

Tags: arrays, math

Hello I am currently trying to make a function that returns true if there is a straight line in an array. For example lets say I have an array

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
0,1,0,0,1 1,1
```

Any suggestions and to how I would check for lines.

Comment: Is this a 1-d array or a 2-d array?

Comment: 2d my apologies I will edit that in

Comment: what is it really? Is it a `int[][]` ? A `std::array<std::array<int,M>,N>` ?

Comment: `std::find(std::begin(matrix), std::end(matrix), [](const auto& row) { return  std::all_of(std::begin(row), std::end(row), [&](const auto& e){ return e == row[0]; });});`?

Comment: `std::ranges::find(matrix, [](const auto& row) { return  std::ranges::all_of(row, [&](const auto& e){ return e == row[0]; });});` with `ranges` :)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 it is declared as int arr[3][3]

Comment: Your example has more numbers than a `int arr[3][3]` can contain.  Maybe its time you showed some code (as text)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the length and height of the array you could do a nested for loop in which you can add up all the numbers in a given row and check if they equal the length of that given row